# Typesetting Go Diagrams with sgf2dg

Tags: macros

This is a question about typesetting diagrams for the [Game of Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_(game)) using the `sgf2dg` tools (currently in their version 4.252 available at their [CPAN home](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Games-Go-Sgf2Dg/)). 
The `sgf2dg` tools can be used to create go diagrams from sgf files (smart game format) and to annotate the diagrams as in this example:

[image: Example for a Go diagram]

The diagrams look very nice to me and I would like to add comments with numbered stones as well. The `sgf2dg` TeX library `gooemacs.sty` makes available the command `\textstone{}` for exactly that purpose. The lines

```
This is a black stone: \textstone{\goo\003@}
This is a smaller black stone: {\setGoFonts at 1.8ex \textstone{\goo\003@}}
```

produce the nice output of:

[image: example of textstone command]

### Now my problem

The `\textstone{}` command does everything I want for a price: The input of the go stone's label has to be in that specific `\goo` (or `\goe`) format as a four digit code. In the example above `\goo\003@` will produce a black stone labeled 3. `\goo` (and their relatives `\goe`, `\bgoo` and `\bgoe`) are font selection mechanisms. Here is the definition of `\goo` from the package `gooemacs.sty`:

```
\def\goo{\offinterlineskip\parindent=0pt\parskip=0pt\obeylines%black odd, white even
\setbox0\hbox{\gooegb +}\global\goIntWd=\wd0\global\goIntHt=\ht0\global\goTextAdj=2pt%
\def\0##1##2##3{\if##1?\gooegb ##3 \else \gooa\char##1##2 \fi}%
\def\1##1##2##3{\if##1?\gooegb ##3 \else \goob\char##1##2 \fi}%
\def\2##1##2##3{\if##1?\gooegb ##3 \else \gooc\char##1##2 \fi}%
\def\3##1##2##3{\if##1?\gooegb ##3 \else \good\char##1##2 \fi}%
\def\4##1##2##3{\if##1?\gooegb ##3 \else \gobl\char##1##2 \fi}%
\def\5##1##2##3{\if##1?\gooegb ##3 \else \gowl\char##1##2 \fi}%
\def\-##1##2{\gooegb ##1}%
\def\!##1{\leavevmode\hbox to \goIntWd{\hss\raise\goTextAdj\hbox{\rm ##1}\hss}}% #1 on empty intersections
}
```

I do, however, consider their encryption as too complicated to think about while writing my go diagram's annotation.

For annotating the diagrams I want to use a high (higher) level LaTeX macro like `\Black{}`.
I want to write `\Black{3}` in my source code and then have it transformed to its corresponding `\goo\003@`.

### Question

My attempt was to define a new command like:

```
\newcommand{\Black}[1]{%
\ifnum #1 >299 {\goo\#1@}\fi%
}
\Black{301}
```

but the replacement `#1` fails (because of the preceding `\` I guess) and produces the output \#1. How can I prevent that? How can I have TeX replace #1 and put it right after a backslash?

### Remarks

I do realize there are more problems to solve: font selection based on even/odd label number, missing leading zeros with smaller stone numbers (1-99).

If you try to convert an sgf file to tex be aware of a bug in `sgf2dg`'s version 4.252: [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38412658/sgf2dg-and-perl-use-of-uninitialized-value-in-pattern-match-m).

The change of font size command in `gooemacs.sty` (`\setGoFonts at #1`) is missing end-of-line-`%`s, see [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines).

---

As a MWE I attach some working TeX code with the `sgf2dg` package. As mentioned above my attempt at `\Black{}` failed and is not included here.
The example requires the installation of `sgf2dg` package (with gooemacs), which is also available on many Linux distributions.

```
\documentclass[margin=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{gooemacs}

\begin{document}
This is a black stone: \textstone{\goo\003@}
This is a smaller black stone: {\setGoFonts at 1.8ex \textstone{\goo\003@}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\Black{3} in my source code and then have it transformed to its corresponding \goo\003@`  would be `\newcommand\Black[1]{\goo\00#1@}` but your suggested code is trying something else testing for 299? (sorry not playing go, it's hard to guess what the intended usage is here)

Comment: Your suggestion works for Black single digit labels 1-9. `\Black{13}` for example fails: \goo\013@ intended, but \goo\0013@ received.

Comment: oh as i say that's easily fixed but I don't know what the input or output should be except in the case you mentioned. `\goo\003@`  is 5 tokens  `\goo`, `\0`, `0`, `3`, `@`   so for `\Black` do you want the first two tokens always to be `\goo\0` the last token always to be `@` and the middle two tokens to be a number `#1` padded with a leading zero if less than 10 ? or do you sometimes need 3 digit input and change the `\0` token ?

Comment: I have added the definition of `\goo` in the question. I require input up to `\Black{399}` (this is how many labels are offered by the fonts). They need token `\0` for labels up to 99 (with additional zero for single digits), then `\1` for 100-199, `\2` for 200-299 and lastly `\3` for 300-399

Comment: yes I had the macro from the code site but  didn't want to guess the range of inputs:-) that code seems to be doing testing for `?` in the input as well, which isn't handled by my answer

Comment: indeed, `?` is used for a handful of special symbols like triangle or square as label for a go stone. Eventually I want to be able to handle `\Black{triangle}` or that sort, but I havn't asked about that yet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the requirements I think

```
\Black{3}

\Black{41}

\Black{99}

\Black{555}
```

produces

```
testing:\goo\003@
testing:\goo\041@
testing:\goo\099@
testing:\goo\555@
```

In this version just echoed to the terminal, remove the `\goo` definition for your real code.

```
\documentclass{article}

%this line just for testing without the go package
\def\goo#1@{\typeout{testing:\string\goo\string#1@}}

\newcommand\Black[1]{{%
\count0=#1\relax
\divide\count0 by 100\relax
\count2=\numexpr#1-100*\count0\relax
\count4=\count2\relax
\divide\count2 by 10
\count4=\numexpr\count4-10*\count2\relax
\edef\tmp{\noexpand\goo
\expandafter\noexpand\csname\the\count0\endcsname
\the\count2
\the\count4
@}\tmp
}}
\begin{document}


\Black{3}

\Black{41}

\Black{99}

\Black{555}


\end{document}
```

Comment: While attempting to use part of your answer I stumbled upon your `\tmp`. Why doesn't just `{\goo\csname #1@\endcsname}` work (assuming `#1` is a three digit number)? or `{\expandafter\goo\csname #1@\endcsname}` for that matter?

Comment: @flobo you need all three arguments to `\goo` to be single tokens, so you need to expand `\csname #1@\endcsname` for the first and `\the\count2` for the second and `\the\count4` for the third  before `\goo` is executed, it would be possible to chain several `\expandafter` but the `\edef` method is simpler here.

Comment: @flobo no `\csname #1@\endcsname` would be completely the wrong thing! that would make, given 123 a command with name 123  but `\123` as used in `\goo\123` is `\1` followed by `2` and `3` that is why above I have to do the arithmetic to get the "hundreds" value before passing just that digit to `\csname` that is you need to make `\goo{\1}{2}{3}@` from an argument of 123

Answer (score 3):

In this answer I present a solution that works for even numbered stones as well as for letter markings.
Instead of writing a high level macro for `\goo` we replace it by a new font selection mechanism `\mygo`.

[image: font test Black]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{gooemacs}

\def\mygo{%
  \def\a##1##2##3{\ifodd ##3 \gooa\char##2##3 \else \goea\char##2##3\fi}% 1 - 99
  \def\b##1##2##3{\ifodd ##3 \goob\char##2##3 \else \goeb\char##2##3\fi}% hundreds
  \def\c##1##2##3{\ifodd ##3 \gooc\char##2##3 \else \goec\char##2##3\fi}% two hundreds
  \def\d##1##2##3{\ifodd ##3 \good\char##2##3 \else \goed\char##2##3\fi}% three hundreds
  \def\s##1{\gooegb##1}%
  \def\t##1##2{\gobl\char##1##2}% if label, subst 2 for ##1 ??
}

\newcommand{\Black}[1]{%
\if!\ifnum9<1#1!\fi% if it's a number:
{\ifnum #1<10 {\mygo\a00#1}%
  \else \ifnum #1<100 {\mygo\a0#1}%
  \else \ifnum #1<200 {\mygo\b#1}%
  \else \ifnum #1<300 {\mygo\c#1}%
  \else \ifnum #1<400 {\mygo\d#1}%
  \fi% larger numbers will not be printed, no error message.
  \fi%
  \fi%
  \fi%
  \fi}%
\else%if it's a letter:
{\mygo\t\numexpr`#1-`\a+1\relax}\fi%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{5cm}

\Black{1}\Black{2}\Black{11}\Black{12}\Black{111}\Black{112}\Black{211}\Black{212}\Black{311}\Black{312}\\
\Black{a}\Black{b}\Black{c}\Black{d}\Black{e}\Black{f}\Black{g}\Black{h}\Black{i}\Black{j}

\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

The solution can easily be extended for White stones.

---

Possible extensions/improvements:
I wonder if the number of conditionals can be reduced. The order of the if-then-else structure might better test for letters first, as one is more likely to comment on Black a than on Black 312?

Also, symbols are not supported yet. I wonder if optional arguments are the way to go here. For example like `\Black[t]{}` for a Black stone marked with a triangle. The definition of `\mygo` is prepared for this with `\def\s##1{\gooegb##1}%` (`\gooegb` is `sgf2dg` font of marked stones).

Comment: oh, I wasn't aware I could only pick one. put it back though

Comment: No need really I probably have enough ticks to survive:-)